# Limitar decimales a inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy calculando el **IVA** de un valor y cuando ingreso el numero en decimales me arroja como ressultado muchos decimales tanto en el **IVA** como en el `input` total y quiero limitarlo para que solo pueda ser hasta 2.

```html
<tfoot>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label class="text-center" for=""> <b>SUBTOTAL</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="subtotal" class="form-control" onkeyup="calculoIva();">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label class="text-center" for=""> <b>IVA (12%)</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="iva" class="form-control" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label class="text-center" for=""> <b>TOTAL</b></label>
    <input id="totalfact" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</tfoot>
```

**Codigo js:**

```js
function calculoIva() {
  var tasaIva = 12;
  var monto = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;

  var iva = (monto * tasaIva) / 100;
  $("#iva").val(iva);

  $("#totalfact").val(parseFloat(monto) - parseFloat(iva));
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes hacerlo  desde HTML, solo cambia el tipo de campo a número y agrega el paso mínimo: `<input type="number" id="subtotal" step="0.01">`

Comment: no funciono ya lo intente

Comment: Combina con la solución propuesta en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo lo pude resolver el código js quedo así:

```
function calculoIva() {

    var tasaIva = 12;
    var monto = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;
    var IVATotal = (monto * tasaIva) / 100;
    iva.value= IVATotal.toFixed(2);
    const a = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;
    const b = document.getElementById("iva").value;
    totalfact.value=((a-b).toFixed(2));
    
};
```

En el HTML no modifique nada

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion `toFixed()`.

```js
const a = 20.5632;
const b = 20.5632;
console.log((a + b).toFixed(2));
```

Ver mas acerca de **JavaScript Number toFixed()** [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)